# Can't get xterm to work. DISPLAY not set.

Tags: xorg

Here are my settings:

```
$ xterm
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm:  DISPLAY is not set

$ echo $DISPLAY

$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

Comment: did you use -X when you ssh in ? `ssh -X user@server` ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: That was it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the -X flag

```
ssh -X user@server
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was missing the xauth program on the target machine

How to debug these situations:

1. On the target host, run another sshd daemon to debug on another port:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 222
   ```
2. On the source host:

   ```
   ssh -v -Y phil@192.168.0.14 -p 222
   ```

In my situation I could see:

```
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.
```

(Note: to run sshd on another port you may need to modify or temporarily disable iptables : `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`, or equivalent)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this command:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xterm
```

Comment: @alessandrefac93 - that will not work over ssh.

Comment: It won't work of ssh, but it's quite useful for those of us who are just trying to Xterm working without ssh. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `vncpasswd` in the account you used to write the configuration file?

I had this problem because I configured the `root` account but the `vnc` user is another, run the `vncpasswd` again in the right account and everything will be ok.

Comment: Question is regarding xterm not working due to display not set. nothing to do vnc. protocol used to access can be anything eg: ssh