# Ubuntu does not start after installing tomcat

Tags: 14.04, boot, ubuntu-gnome, tomcat

I have installed tomcat 8 and shutdown my laptop. Now when I start it after login it doesn't show anything. Right click is also disabled and only the splash screen appears with wallpaper. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. When I log in to a guest session, my own user or gnome desktop the same thing happens.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to got to `tty` and log in, now run this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: But where should I write it.I can not open terminal or any application its not visible

Comment: On login screen you can access tty by pressing *Ctrl+Alt+F1*. To exit press *Ctrl +Alt+F7*

Comment: @Olimjon I enetered in that mode what should I do to get my GUI desktop still it does not appear.

Comment: @mark when I am applying first command it says error "cannot autolaunch D-Bus without $DISPLAY" because Display variable not set

Comment: Drashti - you need to ask @ashu about this solution, I did not write it, I am sure he can help, this comment will notify him.

Comment: @DrashtiPandya. Please refer to this thread 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/289719/cant-get-xterm-to-work-display-not-set' regarding display. In my case 'echo $DISPLAY' gives this output ':0'.

Comment: @ashu have set display variable to 0.but error is spawing command line 'dbus-lunch--autolaunch' child process exit with code 1

Comment: @DrashtiPandya. Refer this thread 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/323776/gsettings-not-working-over-ssh'

Comment: @ashu why did I need to set Display var everytime in same login.export DISPLAY=host:server in my case host is localhost and server is xyz name.